# Turn off AutoComplete in Visual Studio 2010 "Find" Box

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to disable the autocomplete in VS2K10's FIND box in the menu bar?  I find it incredibly irritating to have to paste a parameter name into the find box in order to get around autocomplete filling in a totally different parameter name, which happens to start with the same letter as the param I'm looking for.  I've seen the suggestions for disabling autocomplete in IntelliSense, but didn't yet try them since it seemed unrelated.  Am I mistaken?

Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been "sort of" answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/233335/visual-studio-10-disable-find-autocomplete). I say "sort of" as its behaviour is likely causing your issue as well.

There is another work around [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vseditor/thread/f39b7a2d-93d3-4e62-8906-4f3a65aee310).

Comment: Thanks.  That's a truly atrocious feature, and is one of the very few things that have really gotten under my skin about VS2K10.